# Performance: Put soundex in DB or translate it after the query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, database-performance

I am relative new in MySQL. I do have a forum and I am writing a search function for this. The query is getting all entries of the forum. I want to combine a search algorithm [similar_text() & soundex()].

My question now due to performance. Is it better now that I am going to save the soundex code in the database when I am writing a new entry to the datasae? Or is it better due to performance to translate each entry in soundex()?

I am using symfony2 framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The soundex algorithm was designed to index Anglo-Saxon last names by their sound when pronounced in English. If you're trying to index forum text--something like the questions and answers on StackOverflow--instead of names, it's probably not a good choice. Look into [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) instead.

Having said that, if you happen to be indexing last names, you'll *almost certainly* get better performance by storing the encoding. Ideally, you'd include a CHECK constraint to guarantee that the encoding would be updated if the name changed, but MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK constraints. You'd need to write triggers to keep the two columns in sync.

An alternative on most platforms would be to create an index on value returned by soundex() (or whatever function you use).  Something like `create index on your_table (soundex(your_column));`. But MySQL doesn't support indexes on expressions.